# Can't boot from USB, bios key doesn't work

Tags: linux, windows, boot, usb

I have a computer with Linux Mint 17.2 installed. Now I want to install Windows 10 in a second partition, but the problem is, I can't access the bios to change the boot order, I don't know why, I have tried everything, but is impossible, something is failing. So, I can't boot from usb, or even boot from cd to install windows. The only weapons I have is: 
- Linux Mint installed with grub2. 
- Refind boot manager installed, so I can have multiple os to boot in uefi mode.
- Windows installed on a virtual machine, so I can do some windows things from here.

Please, I really need help with this, I don't found a solution.

Appreciate your help

Comment: "I don't know why, I have tried everything, but is impossible, something is failing" - What exactly have you tried?

Comment: rEFInd has an option to boot to firmware setup. Use it. Your computer should have a special key on boot to enter firmware setup and another special key(F10 usually) to enter boot device selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you cannot enter firmware for setup or boot device selection (which sounds strange - is firmware password protected?) you could create a boot entry in grub2 for booting USB (or DVD). GRUB can boot/chain load everything bootable!

On UEFI firmware use [efibootmgr](http://linux.dell.com/files/efibootmgr/efibootmgr-0.5.4/efibootmgr.txt) for handling boot entries in NVRAM. For example you can set what OS or device to boot next.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't noticed you have answered. So, the past year was this problem, and my solution was that you say. Whit grub I managed to access the usb and boot Windows installer. That was hard to find the correct commands, but I could install windows perfectly. After that, I made a downgrade to the bios, then upgrade again, and the bios started working perfectly. Well, hard times, but now my computer is working well. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset yout BIOS; then you can enter in boot options. You need to take out the battery from the motherboard, wait 2 minutes, then put it back.

Comment: or there might be a button on the motherboard.